# Is there any database of malicious code for MIPS processor to evaluate detection method?

Tags: assembly, mips

I need a database of malicious code for MIPS processor Assembly or C to inject in Mibench and evaluate my detection mechanism at run time.
Is there anything like this for MIPS? what about for other processors?

Don't we have any attack benchmark for this purpose?

Comment: Way back in the day (DOS/Windows 3.1 era) one used to be able to buy CDs at computer shows that were loaded with binaries and sources for all kinds of captured viruses.  I haven't seen repositories like that since computer shows all died off.

Comment: You might consider asking this on the [Reverse engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) site of SE.